# Relaciónar valores de dos tablas upu0p7up

Tags: php, mysql

UpTengo dos tablas, en las cuales quiero realizar una búsqueda.
En la tabla 1 tengo estos dos valores

Juanito 18años

En tabla 2 tengo estos dos valores.

Juanito imagen.jpg

Lo que quiero hacer es que muestre esto

Juanito 18años imagen.jpg

Tomando en cuenta que la información a mostrar pertenece al mismo Juanitoup

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT TABLA_1.NOMBRE, TABLA_1.EDAD, TABLA_2.FOTO FROM TABLA_1
JOIN TABLA_2
ON TABLA_1.NOMBRE = TABLA_2.NOMBRE
```

Query para dejarlo en vista:

```
CREATE VIEW MI_VISTA AS SELECT TABLA_1.NOMBRE, TABLA_1.EDAD, TABLA_2.FOTO FROM TABLA_1
JOIN TABLA_2
ON TABLA_1.NOMBRE = TABLA_2.NOMBRE
```

Según la estructura de la tabla en tu comentario, debería funcionar. Dejare una url de ejemplo:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fbbae/3

Comment: pues ya le hice el intento es que estoy utilizando la sentencia like % para hacer una busqueda multiple y me marca error.

$sql ="select personas.nombre, personas.edad, imagenes.imagen, from personas LEFT JOIN imagenes ON personas.nombre=imagenes.nombre where nombre like '".$nombre."%' AND edad like '".$edad."%' LIMIT 1";

lo que yo quiero es escribir su nombre y al momento de de que me aparesca su nombre tambien me aparesca su imagen pero tomando la imagen relacionada de la tabla imagenes.

Comment: podrías publicar la estructura y datos de la tabla para que la comunidad podamos entender mejor tu situación.

Comment: Tabla personas:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personas (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,edad VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Tabla imágenes:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imagenes (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,imagen VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Dejé una url en la respuesta donde pruebo una query con dicha estructura